# Rails 5: dynamic table ID access in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In Index view I have table where I'd like to populate ID dynamically. 
So far I tried this:

`id="table_<%= @controller_name %>"`

Method in controller:

```
def get_controller_name
  @controller_name = self.class.name.split("::").last
end
```

Then I want to access particular Table in my Coffeescript. I've done it like this:

```
$ ->
  myvar = '<%= raw @controller_name.to_json %>'
  myvarAsObj = JSON.parse(myvar)
  $('#' + 'table_' + myvarAsObj).DataTable
```

however it doesn't seem to be working.
I see in Page Source I got Table ID like this:
`id="table_MyController"`

**How do I access my table ID in Coffeescript correctly, please?** Thank you!

**Update**

Table in Index:

```
<table data-controller-name="<%= @controller_name %>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" 
data-source="<%= campaign_campaigns_index_path(format: :json) %>">
```

Coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  $('table[data-controller-name]').each ->
    $(this).DataTable
    ajax: $('table[data-controller-name]').each ->
      $(this).data('source')
```

Page Source:

```
<table data-controller-name="CampaignsController" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"
  data-source="/en/campaigns.json">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `<%= raw ...%>` in your coffeescript is interpreted literally. I've always had more success passing any data from Rails to Coffeescript through HTML data attributes, rather than trying to interpolate it. Using data-attributes also reduces coupling between the rails and javascript code.

You could do something like this:

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
def get_controller_name
  @controller_name = self.class.name.split("::").last
end
```

**CampaignsController.rb**

```
def index
  # Render your data as JSON. Example data from the DataTables site:
  render json: {
      data: [
        [
          "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$3,120"
        ],
        [
          "Garrett Winters", "Director", "Edinburgh", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$5,300"
        ]
      ]
    }
end
```

**home.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('table[data-controller-name]').each ->
    el = $(this)

    el.DataTable {
      ajax: el.data('source')
    }
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<table data-controller-name="<%= controller.get_controller_name %>"
       data-source="<%= campaign_campaigns_index_path(format: 'json') %>">
   <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Column 1</th>
         <th>Column 2</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
           <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
           <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The coffeescript will act on any tables that have a `data-controller-name` attribute.

---

**Update** For completeness, you can [parse ERB tags](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb) by appending `.erb` to the Coffeescript filename, e.g:

**home.coffee.erb**

```
$ ->
  $('#table_<%= @controller_name %>').DataTable {
    ajax: el.data('source')
  }
```

However, I still suggest the HTML `data-attributes` approach above for its flexibility and decoupling Coffee/Javascript from the Rails code.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying your suggestion, however I get this error: `NoMethodError ... private method get_controller_name called for` Is it because my controller method is private?

Comment: Could you, please, check my Update above? I added more code to have full picture of what I have at the moment after your suggestion. It still does not work properly, however maybe you notice some error I'm making.

Comment: @matiss Are you getting any error messages logged in the Javascript console (View->Developer->Javascript Console on Chrome)? The `get_controller_name` method will need to be public (or pop it into `ApplicationHelper`)

Also, you might need to escape the `<%= campaign_campaigns_index_path(format: :json) %>` 

Do you a couple of lines of example data you could post?

Comment: @matiss Took another look and have updated my answer accordingly. The coffeescript just needed a bit of tweaking. I've used sample data from the DataTables documentation. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I just found out I probably don't need dynamic table ID in my view. I'm trying to implement Datatables StateSave server side [from this tutorial](http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-state-save-client-server-side/) I have created table where in "name" column I would save table name. I found out I can just pass Controller name there and then search back "state" value reading Controller name. Basically I should be doing all that in controller side, not in my View.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it helped.